# PHP7.1 using memcached as save handler, session start slow

Tags: php, session, memcached, php-7.1

I used memcached as session save handler, and configured in `php.ini` as below:

`session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11311"`

and other options is default.

When running in `php7.1.0` there will be `session_start()` slow log.

I am tested the configuration with `PHP5.5`, and had no this issue.

I want know what's the bug caused by, and which version of php solved or maybe sovle this issue in other way?

There is my full env:

`PHP 7.1.0
libmemcached version => 1.0.18
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar problem with sessions in memcache. In our case it was connected with the session.lazy_write. Once we set session.lazy_write = 0 the session start working fast.

More details can be found here - https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/310.

Doesn't look like your case, but might be useful.